# How to Put SSL In Front of ECS Fargate Container

Tags: ssl-certificate, amazon-ecs

What is the best way to put an SSL cert in front an ECS Fargate Container? I have letsencrypt certs that are being updated every 90 days and uploaded to the SecretsManager and the Certificate Manager. Right now I have a Network Load Balancer and an Application Load Balancer chained together that then point to the ECS Container. This is extremely expensive though because the LBs cost a ton of money. Especially when this is required for every container because all containers need SSL. Any ideas?

Comment: Where exactly in front? Why not at ALB?